# Moving site to another server - inconsistent results between browsers on same computer

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, nameserver, ip-address

I've just moved a site from one server to another. Both servers are under the same Media Temple account - so the nameservers haven't changed, just the IP address.

To help verify the move has taken place, I added a `hello.html` to both servers, which says 'Hello from the (NEW / OLD) server', respectively.

On my laptop, Chrome indicates it's seeing the new server. Firefox, Opera and Safari still say 'hello from the OLD server', despite hard refreshes, cache clears, etc.

Using the IP lookup tool at http://www.hcidata.info/host2ip.cgi, ALL browsers indicate the domain name is pointing to the NEW IP address, despite some of those same browsers showing the OLD hello.html page.

I know DNS changes can take time to propagate, and during that time you can get varying results from different locations. But this is all testing from the same computer.

Any idea as to what's going on? And how to ensure all browsers point to the version of the site on the new server?

======

UDPATE:

So I connected from a different place (work, not home) and everything started seeing the latest version. Then, when I returned home, the latest versions stuck. So, it's all working. I'd still be interested to find out what specifically the issue was before - but I'm guessing it's unlikely I'll ever know for sure!

Comment: Restart the browser(s).

Comment: no luck with restarting the browsers... same situation.

Comment: Are you using a proxy at all?

Comment: nope, no proxy.

Comment: I notice you haven't mentioned what the OS you're accessing the website with is. Your OS can cache domain names as well. On windows ipconfig /dnsflush should work.

Comment: I'm on mac, and yep, that was it - not sure why, but once I cleared the DNS cache at the OS level, it all worked fine. (I moved another site, had the same issue, and that resolved it)

Comment: BTW, @JourneymanGeek if you want to add that as an answer, I'm happy to accept it as correct.

Comment: amusingly, I posted that as an answer, and then realised I wasn't sure how to do it on a Mac and deleted it. Restored the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice you haven't mentioned what the OS you're accessing the website with is. Your *OS* can cache domain names as well. On windows `ipconfig /dnsflush` should work. I'm having trouble finding a definitive way on linux - there's a half dozen different ways to do this - [some listed on the U&L question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67592/how-to-flush-local-dns-cache-in-centos), but none seem to do anything on my test system.

Another possible thing might be your router caching domain names - talk to your network admin about this.

According to the OP on OS X `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder` should work on OS X 10.7 and 10.8, and on Mavericks its `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder - [he referenced this OS X daily article](http://osxdaily.com/2008/03/21/how-to-flush-your-dns-cache-in-mac-os-x/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing the cache on all the browsers that go to the old website.  It's definitely a browser issue where it's caching some information, since your DNS is working fine (pointing to the new server)

Comment: Yes, I thought it must be a cache thing, but I did try disabling and clearing caches.

Comment: Clean uninstall the browser and reinstall, meaning removing every file that is potentially associated with the browser. I suspect stale entries in the cache.